# Python string to array : TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have a string from a field in a query set which looks like this:

[{'thirdParty': 'Funds Transfer'}, {'category': 'External Transfers'}, {'creditDebit': 'credit'}]

I want to be able to loop through the elements in orther to be able to get

```
{'thirdParty': 'Funds Transfer'}
{'category': 'External Transfers'}
{'creditDebit': 'credit'}
```

And also to be able to loop through the keys of that object

I am trying the following but I keep getting an error: TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array

```
import numpy as np
tags = "[{'thirdParty': 'Funds Transfer'}, {'category': 'External Transfers'}, {'creditDebit': 'credit'}]"
# print(type(tags))
# <class 'str'>
arr = list(np.array(tags))
# print(type(tags))
# <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
# print(tags)
# [{'thirdParty': 'Funds Transfer'}, {'category': 'External Transfers'}, {'creditDebit': 'credit'}]
for d in arr:
    print(d)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import ast

tags = "[{'thirdParty': 'Funds Transfer'}, {'category': 'External Transfers'}, {'creditDebit': 'credit'}]"
tags_list = ast.literal_eval(tags)

print(tags_list)
```

### Output:

```
[
    {"thirdParty": "Funds Transfer"},
    {"category": "External Transfers"},
    {"creditDebit": "credit"},
]
```

Answer (score 3):

try this because you added Double quotes in tags

```
import numpy as np
tags = [{'thirdParty': 'Funds Transfer'}, {'category': 'External Transfers'}, {'creditDebit': 'credit'}]
arr = list(np.array(tags))
# print(type(tags))
# <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
# print(tags)
# [{'thirdParty': 'Funds Transfer'}, {'category': 'External Transfers'}, {'creditDebit': 'credit'}]
for d in arr:
    print(d)
```

output

```
{'thirdParty': 'Funds Transfer'}
{'category': 'External Transfers'}
{'creditDebit': 'credit'}
```

Comment: it works perfect when i try from a python online, but not when i try from django, i am wonder why, the error stills: iteration over a 0-d array

Comment: `tags` is already a list...why make a numpy array and then immediately make a list just to get back where you started?

Comment: @MarkMeyer that is not correct when I print(type(key.tags)) i get <class 'str'>, it doesnt said <class 'list'>

Comment: if you give string to numpy array it will show 0-d array you have to give list where you can check lis[0][0]='thirdParty': 'Funds Transfer'.

Comment: @NAGARAJS exactly that is precisely my question